# Dojo drag and drop gets angry after adding new row

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, dojo, draggable

I have a table with draggable rows in Dojo. When I dynamically add new row in table through javascript it creates problem while dragging newly created row. On console it shows 
**Failed to load source**. Yet it drags other rows that was already in table.

While creating new row I also give my row this class `class="dojoDndItem"`. My `<tbody>` is `<tbody dojoType="dojo.dnd.Source">`

Do I need to do something special while creating new row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem that dojo was not updating it draggable nodes. Also by viewing source was not displaying newly created rows. Dojo dnd source has a property called **autoSync**. See [dojo.dnd.Source api](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.3/dojo/dnd/Source). Its by default set to false but enabling it true does the work. It automatically syncs the nodes and all newly generated nodes was able to drag and drop.

So after this  becomes `<tbody dojoType="dojo.dnd.Source" autoSync="true">`

Answer (score 0):

Could you try using the insertNodes method on your dnd source dijit?  I think just adding the nodes with javascript will not trigger the DND source's code that registers it as a draggable element and set up the event listeners.